# Azure - Reading local files from Static Web Page

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I am trying out `static web pages` service from `Azure`. But I need to access a list of files (for example images stored on the server) from the client side. I am trying to implement a `Function` that will iterate over the files in a particular folder and return a list of names.

The problem is that I simply cannot access those files. It can't find them from the context in which the `Function` runs as if they are stored on another machine.

I now use this function to print the folders and files accessible to the python.

**This is the function I used called `GetResources`:**

```
import logging
import os
import sys
import azure.functions as func
import json

import os

def showFolderTree(path):
    show_files=True
    indentation=1
    file_output=False

    tree = []
    result=""
    if not show_files:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            level = root.replace(path, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' '*indentation*(level)
            tree.append('{}{}/'.format(indent,os.path.basename(root)))

    if show_files:
        for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
            level = root.replace(path, '').count(os.sep)
            indent = ' '*indentation*(level)
            tree.append('{}{}/'.format(indent,os.path.basename(root)))    
            for f in files:
                subindent=' ' * indentation * (level+1)
                tree.append('{}{}'.format(subindent,f))
                
    for line in tree:
        result+=line+"\n"
    return result

def main(req: func.HttpRequest, context: func.Context) -> func.HttpResponse:
    # logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')  --> where is this logged?
    try:
        errors=context.function_directory+"\n"
    except Exception as e:
        error="context error\n"

    try:
        errors+=os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))+"\n"
        errors+=os.getcwd()+"\n"

        errors+=showFolderTree("/")
    except Exception as e:
        errors+=e
    
    return func.HttpResponse(errors,status_code=200)
```

**This function returns:**

```
/home/site/wwwroot/GetResources
/home/site/wwwroot/GetResources
/home/site/wwwroot
/
app/
 .bash_logout
 .bashrc
 .profile
site/
wwwroot/
 .funcignore
 requirements.txt
 proxies.json
 .gitignore
 host.json
GetResources/
 function.json
 sample.dat
 __init__.py
__pycache__/
 __init__.cpython-38.pyc
.python_packages/
lib/
site-packages/
azure/
functions/
...
```

but I cannot find my files in the list.

**Observations:**

- The `Python` code runs on a `linux` environment
- I tried a similar code with `C#` and a `Windows` environment running on Azure
- I tried placing a folder of `assets` with pictures in the `api` folder in which the function resides. Still could not find the files.

What am I doing wrong?

**Note**: I have a student subscription

**Side issue**: I cannot find anywhere the logs generated by the `Function` (generated by the logging function)

Answer (score 0):

While Azure Static Web Apps act as a proxy to Azure Functions for APIs, the Functions themself are hosted separate to the Static Web App and don't share the filesystem.

So, instead of having these files pushed alongside the Web App, they should be stored in [Blob Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-introduction) and from Functions, you could leverage [Blob Storage Bindings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob) to read/write them. To list files in a container, you need to bind to [BlobContainerClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-input?tabs=csharp#additional-types) and use a method like [BlobContainerClient.GetBlobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.blobs.blobcontainerclient.getblobs?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Blobs_BlobContainerClient_GetBlobs_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobTraits_Azure_Storage_Blobs_Models_BlobStates_System_String_System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

*Duplicate of my answer on [Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/296818/reading-local-files-from-azure-static-web-page.html?childToView=298079#answer-298079)*